# iPhone - cannot test in-app purchases

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, in-app-purchase

I have created a test account for sandbox testing of in-app purchases. I am following these steps to test

1. Logged out of any existing accounts
2. Open app and start getting list of products available
3. Start process to download a product

   SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:productId];

   [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment: payment];

Now ideally I should be asked for the user name/pwd at this point. But I am not prompted for anything and the transaction fails (obviously because I am not logged in)

If I try to login from Settings->Store, it asks for my credit info which I'm sure is not necessary.

Can someone please help me with this issue.

Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

Ok. This was stupid! But hope someone can learn from my mistakes :)
I was testing the in-app purchase with a adhoc distribution profile. And acc to Apple engineers, as soon as you do that, the test account "stops" being a test account.

In-app purchases CAN ONLY BE TESTED by launching your app via XCode in debug mode!

**Update**

This is not true any more. It supposedly works fine with adhoc builds as well now.

Source: recent testing of in-app purchases using an adhoc build.

Comment: Strange, I pretty sure we succesfully tested in-app purchasing with an ad hoc build.

Comment: This is what the Apple tech support told me.

Comment: I've tested in app purchase from ad-hoc distributions and from debug builds not connected to xcode.

Comment: You can also test it in Release mode.  Ive done it numerous times.

Comment: Even i tested in app purchase from Ad-Hoc distribution... not faced this kind of issue....

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have in-app purchases turned on in your provisioning file

Comment: in-app purchases are turned on. To confirm, you mean my app id should not have a *? It does not. And I'm using the same app id for the products I've added to itunes connect.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check canMakePayments
2. In Simulator the StoreKit just does not respond : you should test on the device
3. You must have at least one observer added to the SKPaymentQueue
4. Try to ask for the product list first (besides the fact that you know the productId already); it sounds silly, but SK framework is far from perfect.

Also, when sending {"receipt-data":...} to verification server do encode the receipt with Base64 before inserting it into json object. This is not mentioned in official docs anywhere: only on a couple of blogs.

Comment: 1. Thanks. will try
2. testing on a device and i don;t get the prompt for uname/pwd
3. Have an observer already. thats where the failed transaction info comes up
4. Getting the product list in the beginning only.
The problem is I don;t see the alert which asks for uname/pwd!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. As suggested by Oleg, the issue was that the productID was invalid. Set a break point at

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response and check response.products.
```

You may find that the productID is not in response.products. When this happen, the transaction will proceed as  purchase cancel by user, therefore, never prompt for login.